# Functional binary search tree in kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, functional-programming

I want to implement a binary search tree in kotlin.

```
class BinarySearchTree<out T>
object Nil : BinarySearchTree<Nothing>
val a: BinarySearchTree<Int> = Nil // works fine
```

However, to add an element of type `K` to the tree I need the type `K` to extend `T` and implement `Comparable<T>`.
If I use the following code, then I get an error

```
fun <K> add(b : K) where K : T, K : Comparable<T> {}
```

> Error: Type T is declared as 'out', but occures in 'in' position in type T.

How can I fix the interface of this method or the class to get rid of the problem?

Comment: You could change `out T` to `T : Comparable<T>`, and then change the `add` function to just `fun add(b: T)`. You cannot have `out` on the type parameter and at the same time use it as input to a function.

Comment: Then I cannot use something like `val a: BinarySearchTree<Int> = Nil`

Comment: Right. You could write `add` as an extension function though. Something like `fun <T : Comparable<T>> BinarySearchTree<T>.add(t: T): BinarySearchTree<T>`. The `Comparable<T>` constraint will only be enforced on calls to `add` though.